# How do I get the sum of a column where another column's item value = a value?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

My code:

```
string hweight = "Hunters";
string hsql = "SELECT SUM(Weight), Product From Opened WHERE Product =" + hweight;

OleDbCommand hcmd = new OleDbCommand(hsql,conn);
txtHunters.Text = hcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Then i receive the following error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Product' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: You are missing the `group by` clause.

Comment: And SQL quotes around your string.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL should be:

```
SELECT SUM(Weight), Product From Opened WHERE Product =" + hweight + " GROUP BY Product"
```

When you are using aggregated functions you should group them by something! In you case the product field!

Answer (score 2):

You try to select a field / column and use an aggregate function at the same time, that only works if you provide a `group by` clause for the selected field / column as well:

```
string hsql = "SELECT SUM(Weight), Product FROM Opened WHERE Product ='" + hweight + "' GROUP BY Product";
```

Comment: Thanks, I mostly write field, for me they refer to the same thing - will include column as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string hweight = "Hunters";
string hsql = "SELECT SUM(Weight), Product From Opened WHERE Product =" + hweight + " GROUP BY Product";
OleDbCommand hcmd = new OleDbCommand(hsql,conn);
txtHunters.Text = hcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```